# What's wrong with this C code for finding HCF?

Tags: c, code-snippets

I wrote this funky piece of code when I had just learnt while loops in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int dd,dr,q,r;
    printf("Enter bigger no: ");
    scanf("%d",&dd);
    printf("Enter smaller no: ");
    scanf("%d",&dr);
    while(dr>0)
    {
        r=dd%dr;
        dd=dr;
        dr=r;
    }
    printf("HCF=%d",dr);
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t",dd,q,r);
    return(0);
}
```

Enter bigger/smaller no. was to keep things simplified. This program works properly. Now, as soon as I remove the line above return statement `printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t",dd,q,r);`, the hcf changes to 0. What causes this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you´re printing as HCF (GCD) is always 0,
because it´s `dr` and the loop runs until `dr` is 0.

The "problem" is that you´re printing `dd` after `dr` without any space etc.between them,
so it appears as one number. If you remove the second printf, only the 0 of `dr` remains.
Insert `\n` between the outputs, and switch the variables to print the right thing.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was wondering why that 0 was coming everytime. Now I get It. HCF is stored in dd as James said below.

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop is checking that `dr > 0` to exit your while loop `dr` must be 0. I think that your HCF will be in `dd` not `dr` at the end of the while loop. The algorithm you're using is called Euclid's algorithm so you could check this by looking the algorithm up.